# Check if a key value already exists in a multidimensional array object in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose I have an array with object like this

```
array = [
           {id:2,cnt:2},{id:3,cnt:3},{id:4,cnt:2},
           {id:1,cnt:6},{id:2,cnt:7},{id:5,cnt:4},
           {id:2,cnt:4},{id:3,cnt:2},{id:4,cnt:2},
           {id:3,cnt:2},{id:4,cnt:3},{id:5,cnt:2}
       ];
```

where I need to create another array with the object where I need to add `cnt` value with `id`.

Output suppose to be like this.

```
output = [
           {id:1,cnt:6},{id:2,cnt:13},{id:3,cnt:7},{id:4,cnt:7},{id:5,cnt:6}
         ];
```

what I have tried so far is

```
var general = [];
  angular.forEach(array, function(value){
    angular.forEach(value, function(val,key){
      angular.forEach(general, function(val1,key1){
         if(val1.id === val.id){
             val1.cnt +=val.cnt
            //@TOD0 how to add value of count and put it on general
         }else{
            //@TODO
            general.push(val);            
         }
      });                 

    });
  });

console.log(general);
```

I am unable to achieve my output.  I have marked as TODO where I am confused. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Invalid syntax for `array` variable

Comment: invalid desired output.

Comment: I apologize for my mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var arr  = [ 
{id:2,count:2,color:"red"},{id:3,count:3,color:"black"},{id:4,count:2,color:"white"}, 
{id:1,count:6,color:"green"},{id:2,count:7,color:"red"},{id:5,count:4,color:"blue"}, 
{id:2,count:4,color:"red"},{id:3,count:2,color:"black"},{id:4,count:2,color:"white"}, 
{id:3,count:2,color:"black"},{id:4,count:3,color:"red"},{id:5,count:2,color:"blue"} 
];
var obj={};
arr.forEach(function(a){
obj[a.id]=obj[a.id]||[0];
obj[a.id][0]=obj[a.id][0]+a["count"];
obj[a.id][1]=a.color;
})
//console.log(obj);
var brr=Object.keys(obj).map(function(a){
return {"id":a,"count":obj[a][0],"color":obj[a][1]};
})

console.log(brr);
```

Comment: How to add if I have more key value pair in above code?

Comment: give input and see

Comment: obj[a.id]=obj[a.id]+a["cnt"]+a['newval'];? small hint please. I am back-end programmer and don't have good understanding of javascript.

Comment: no code will be same . just change input (arr) and see

Comment: I add one more key-value pair in arr.What I need to get this color key in array?Please help me.I spend lot of time in this and I am not also javascript programmer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130135/discussion-between-dev-and-mahi).

Answer (score 2):

`Array.reduce` can help you a lot - you basically create a new array, and iterate your current array and check the new array to see if the current item exists. If it does, add the `cnt` - else add the whole item:

```
var mashed = arr.reduce(function(m, cur, idx) {
    var found = false;
    for (var i =0; i < m.length; i++) {
        if (m[i].id == cur.id) {
            m[i].cnt += cur.cnt;
            found = true;
        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        m.push(cur)
    }

    return m;
}, [])
```

Fiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1ffqv9g0/

Comment: @Mahi - That's because OP's math was wrong. If you add up all the `cnt` for id `2` - it'll add to 13

Comment: yeah i know... :)

Comment: and i suggest you to use `break` after `found=true`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table for the result. For an ordered result, you could sort the result.

```js
var array = [{ id: 2, cnt: 2 }, { id: 3, cnt: 3 }, { id: 4, cnt: 2 }, { id: 1, cnt: 6 }, { id: 2, cnt: 7 }, { id: 5, cnt: 4 }, { id: 2, cnt: 4 }, { id: 3, cnt: 2 }, { id: 4, cnt: 2 }, { id: 3, cnt: 2 }, { id: 4, cnt: 3 }, { id: 5, cnt: 2 }],
    grouped = [];

array.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.id]) {
        this[a.id] = { id: a.id, cnt: 0 };
        grouped.push(this[a.id]);
    }
    this[a.id].cnt += a.cnt;
}, Object.create(null));


grouped.sort(function (a, b) { return a.id - b.id; });
console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: when by page get reload if (!this[a.id]) is not working?My page get refresh with ajax after certain interval of time.

Comment: maybe the original context is lost.

Comment: My page get reload using ajax every 30 sec. when my page get load first is ok. I try to console it.And what i see is,I cannot get inside of if (!this[a.id]) {
        this[a.id] = { id: a.id, cnt: 0 };
        grouped.push(this[a.id]);
    } part of code.

Comment: from far away of your console, i can not really help, sorry.